# Nested Eager Loading in Sequelize for columns referring to the same table not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using `Sequelize` ORM for my `PostgreSQL` relational database. Sequelize has the concept of `nested eager loading` as mentioned in this [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/) which helps to obtain the associations for the given table in the same query.

My `DB Schema` is as follows

[image]

I have tried using nested eager loading as mentioned in this [Link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/) but unable to obtain any associations for my ImageProducts Table

My `nested include` on the `ImageProducts` Table is as follows:

```
 include:[{
            model: models.Tags
            include: [{
                model: models.TagType,
               }],
          }];
```

My `code` is as follows:

```
   var options = {
        where: {
          //where condition
        },
        options: [{
           model: models.Tags
           include: [{
              model: models.TagType,
               }],
          }]
     }
     models.ImageProducts.findAll(options).then(function (response) {
        if (response.length > 0) {
           //Some Logic
        } else {
           // Some other Logic
        }
     }).catch(function (err) {
          // Error Handling
     });
```

Can Somebody help me as to why I am unable to do `nested eager loading` present in sequelize on my `ImageProducts` Table for columns `productType` and `priceRange` which are referring to the same table namely `Tags`?

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
var options = {
    where: {
      //where condition
    },
    include: [{                //<- options is not valid
       model: models.Tags
       include: [{
          model: models.TagType,
           }],
      }]
 }
```

Comment: You should remember to add an 'as' attribute with the same alias you used for the association in the model.

Comment: Hi Hendrul, I Tried this too But Still unable to do nested association on the given model.